Sequelize query to filter records created one year ago based on created_at date
I'm working with Sequelize in a Node.js application and need to write a query that retrieves data where the created_at date is exactly one year old.
Here's the current query I'm using:
const newGrants = await this.Application.findAll({
    where: {
        applied_by: userIds,
    },

    include: {
        model: this.Grant,
        where: {
            // Using a raw SQL literal to add one year to the `created_at` date
            [Op.and]: literal(`"grant"."created_at" <=  interval '1 year'`)
        }
    }
});

However, this query doesn't seem to work as expected. I'm unsure how to correctly format the condition to filter created_at dates between one-year-old.  How can I adjust the query to filter records that were created time is between one year correctly?
I've tried using a raw SQL literal but it doesn't seem to work properly. Any guidance on how to achieve this in Sequelize would be greatly appreciated.
I want to retrieve records from the Grant model where the created_at date is exactly one year after the Grant create  date.

use Sequelize.literal and Sequelize.Op operators to construct appropriate date condition



const { Op } = require('sequelize');

// Assuming your model is named 'YourModel'
const YourModel = require('./path/to/your/model');

// Get the current date
const currentDate = new Date();

// Calculate the date exactly one year ago from the current date
const oneYearAgo = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear() - 1, currentDate.getMonth(), currentDate.getDate(), currentDate.getHours(), currentDate.getMinutes(), currentDate.getSeconds());

// Perform the query
return YourModel.findAll({
  where: {
    createdDate: {
      [Op.gte]: oneYearAgo,
      [Op.lt]: currentDate,
    },
  },
});



You calculate the oneYearAgo date by subtracting one year from the current date's year and keeping the same month, day, hours, minutes, and seconds. Then, we use the Op.gte operator to find records greater than or equal to oneYearAgo, and the Op.lt operator to find records less than currentDate. This way, we retrieve records with a createdDate falling within the last one year.
